# Search in Liferay

Tags: elasticsearch, search, liferay, liferay-dxp, liferay-7.2

I have created one structure which is followed by web content. Structure Contains 2 fields. One is Area name and the second is Zip Code. I stored data in web content followed by this structure. 
I want to search for data based on zip code or area name entered by the user. I want to provide a dropdown to the user to select criteria to search like by Zipcode / by Area name.

The problem is web content data is stored in XML format. So whenever a user searches for a keyword it will return all results which contain given text. I want to restrict that.

I am using this method for search data.

`List<JournalArticle> results = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.search(
                  themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), //company id 
                  themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), // group id 
                  null, //folderIds Log list 
                  0, //classname 
                  null, //version 
                  null,//title 
                  null, //description 
                  searchkeyword, // here  put your keywords  to search
                  new Date(), // startDate 
                  new Date(), // endDate 
                  0, //status 
                  null, //review Date 
                  QueryUtil.ALL_POS, 
                  QueryUtil.ALL_POS, null);`

Comment: Which Liferay Portal version are you using?

Comment: liferay dxp 7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to search using Liferay search API directly to Elasticsearch, filtering by DDM fields.

Each field of webcontent structures are translated to a DDM Field in Elasticsearch side.

You have information about how to query JournalArticle filtering by DDM fields in following links:

- Liferay documentation: https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-2/frameworks/-/knowledge_base/f/search-queries-and-filters
- Stackoverflow 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523689/liferay-6-2-custom-fulltext-search-portlet-implementation#24564208
- Stackoverflow 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982986/get-distinct-values-for-a-group-of-fields-from-a-list-of-records
- Liferay forums 1: https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/108179215
- Liferay forums 2: https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/86997787
- Liferay forums 3: https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/84031533

(note: some links are related to 6.2 version, but 7.x queries should be very similar)

In Liferay Portal 7.x, the names of DDM fields that you have to query are built in DDMIndexerImpl.encodeName(...) method, see:

```
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal-ee/blob/cba537c39989bbd17606e4de4aa6b9ab9e81b30c/modules/apps/dynamic-data-mapping/dynamic-data-mapping-service/src/main/java/com/liferay/dynamic/data/mapping/internal/util/DDMIndexerImpl.java#L243-L268
```

DDM fields names follows following pattern:

- Fields that are configured as keyword: `ddm__keyword__{structrureId}__{fieldname}_{locale}`
- Other fields: `ddm__{structrureId}__{fieldname}_{locale}`

Note: in order to get structureId, you should query DDMStructure filtering by structureKey, if you hardcode the structureId, you can have problems in case you export/import the structure because structureId is recalculated during import process.

Comment: all these links works for liferax 6.x but not in 7.x . Many methods are not available in 7.2 version.